# Redirecting to certain page after logging in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using wordpress. I have a custom login form, and I want to redirect logged in user to /club page, so I added this code:

```
<?php  
$args = array(
        'echo' => true,
        'redirect' => home_url('/club'), 
        'form_id' => 'loginform',
        'label_username' => __( 'Username' ),
        'label_password' => __( 'Password' ),
        'label_remember' => __( 'Remember Me' ),
        'label_log_in' => __( 'Log In' ),
        'id_username' => 'user_login',
        'id_password' => 'user_pass',
        'id_remember' => 'rememberme',
        'id_submit' => 'wp-submit',
        'remember' => true,
        'value_username' => NULL,
        'value_remember' => false );
?>  
<?php wp_login_form( $args ); ?>
```

But redirection is not working.

2. I am using default wordpress login form to out form using `wp_login_form()` and want to have placeholder txt after adding above code still not able to get even label or placeholder text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

redirect to page after login

```
function my_login_redirect( $redirect_to, $request, $user ){
    return home_url('/club-page');
}
add_filter( 'login_redirect', 'my_login_redirect', 10, 3 );
```

Would be easier to inject Placeholder using jquery

using theme functions.php

```
function custom_js_mod() { ?> 
<script>
    (function($){
        $(document).ready( function() {
            $('#user_login').attr('placeholder', 'Enter UserName');
            $('#user_pass').attr('placeholder', 'Enter PassWord');
        });
    })(jQuery);
</script>
<?php
}
add_action('wp_footer','custom_js_mod', 9);
```

or just add it directly on footer.php file

```
<script>
    (function($){
        $(document).ready( function() {
            $('#user_login').attr('placeholder', 'Enter UserName');
            $('#user_pass').attr('placeholder', 'Enter PassWord');
        });
    })(jQuery);
</script>
```

Comment: Hi silver ,Thanks for the reply ,I want to ask you where I can put this jquery ,which file,I am using custom login form

Comment: I added in functions.php ,still it is not showing up ,here is the url docofdetox.com/login